# h2o template not calling child methods

Tags: php

I'm using the h2o library from https://github.com/idlesign/h2o-php and have run into an issue with its variable inspection.

I have an object with child objects that have their own methods. According to the documentation, these should be callable via the dot notation, unfortunately they return empty.

Example:

```
{% for index, object in c.objects %}

    <li>{{ object.name}} | {{ object.method_name }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Outside of the template, the method works:

```
<?
$o = new $ObjectName;
echo $o->childObject[0]->methodName();
?>
```

But calling that with h2o's dot notation ({{objects[0].object.method_name}}) inside the template does not.

As an aside, non-method call variables (object.variableName) are working fine within the template, so its not an issue of the object being null or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to add:

```
var $h2o_safe = array('method_name');
```

Inside the class to make the methods available to the template.